# How can I predict a 2D array over time?

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression

I've got a rectangular region that's composed of 1024 grid cells (32x32 cells). Each of these cells has an associated value, which then builds me a 2D array.

For that 2D array, I've got 8 samples (yearly samples) and I'd like to predict 2 samples ahead. In other words, the data shape is `(8, 32, 32)` (8 samples of the 32x32 grid) and I'd like to predict those `(2, 32, 32)` samples in the future.

Most of the cells, individually, seems to follow an exponential trend. What I've already tried is using each cell, individually, as time-series, but this wouldn't take into account the cell's proximity and growth of neighbor cells, which I guess would improve my model.

I'm aware that the number of samples is tiny, but I wonder if there's any way I could predict the whole 2D array at once. I've read in some places about Vector Autoregression and I've tried using `statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VAR` (Python), but it tells me that there are not enough observations. Besides that, I don't think that neural networks would perform well with this amount of samples. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: You could try using a spatio-temporal Gaussian process, which jointly accounts for dependence in time and in distance along the grid.